# Service call in angular request interceptor causes error

Tags: angularjs

I want to use request interceptor in my app to add verify code into requests (for CSRF protection). My code looks like this now:

```
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $injector, AppConst) {
      return {
          request: function(request) {
              var VerifyCodeService = $injector.get('VerifyCodeService');
              var verifyCodeUrl = AppConst.apiUrl + '/app/verifyCode'

              if(request.url!=verifyCodeUrl && request.data!=undefined){
                  VerifyCodeService.getCode()
                      .then(function(data) {
                          if (AppConst.serviceResponseOk==data.result) {
                              request.data.verifyCode = data.verifyCode;
                              return request;
                          } else {
                              console.log('error');
                              return request;
                          }
                      }, function(error) {
                          console.log('error:' + error);
                          return request;
                      });
              } else {
                  return request;
              }
          }
      };
  });
```

But for some reason I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
at serverRequest (angular.js:10028)
at processQueue (angular.js:14567)
at angular.js:14583
at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15846)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15657)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:15951)
at done (angular.js:10364)
at completeRequest (angular.js:10536)
at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10477)
```

Anyone knows whats happening?

Comment: But I do return the request in all cases...

Answer (score 1):

If I read this right, you are making a XHR which triggers another XHR to get the CSRF token and add it to the original request's data object. I think the issue is the second XHR. This second request is async just like the first, so you can't just return from the `then` method.

Try returning the promise generated by your second XHR in your `if` statement (which is resolved in the inner `then` invocation after the second XHR by `return request;`).

```
         if(request.url!=verifyCodeUrl && request.data!=undefined){
              var secondXhr = VerifyCodeService.getCode()
                  .then(function(data) {
                      if (AppConst.serviceResponseOk==data.result) {
                          request.data.verifyCode = data.verifyCode;
                          return request;
                      } else {
                          console.log('error');
                          return request;
                      }
                  }, function(error) {
                      console.log('error:' + error);
                      return request;
                  });
              return secondXhr; 
          } else {
              return request;
          }
```

From the [Interceptors section](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) of the Angular docs (bolding added):

> request: interceptors get called with a http config object. The
>   function is free to modify the config object or create a new one. The
>   function needs to return the config object directly, **or a promise
>   containing the config or a new config object**.

On a different note, it looks like you are introducing a significant delay into each XHR since you are essentially blocking each request until the token is returned.

A different implementation where each response returns the new token for the next request in a header could work (as long as you don't have concurrent requests(!)), or CSRF token per page load (if you have full page reloads) might be options. I'm sure there are suggestions on the internets if you want to make that change.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but that was not enough, the solution that worked for me is what you posted, PLUS resolving promise immediately with var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.resolve(secondXhr);
  return deferred.promise;

Comment: Nice, glad you sorted it out!